# Freeware File Auditing Software for File Access

Tags: gratis, windows-10, security

Good day,

Can you please recommend me a freeware/open-source solution for file access monitoring on Windows? To give a full background of how our system works currently:

We have a single PC running Windows 10 Pro with two internal drives. The first main drive is for programs on the PC and the secondary drive is used for file storage.
This secondary drive is mapped to each employee's laptop via ethernet and a single username and password is used to access the network drive.

I have tried to use Windows 10's Audit Policy and Event Log to try and determine who has accessed which file. However, since a single login is used to access the drive, I cannot determine who accessed the files, only when which file was accessed.

Do you have any recommendations for Freeware or Open-Source software which I can use to monitor which laptop accessed which files and when.

Advice on how to effectively do this using Audit Policies will also be appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why not use the Windows permissions system as intended? Put all users into a group and allow access to the group.

Comment: Won't all the users be the same due to the use of the same login when authenticating access to the network drive? My situation current is that I cannot create logins for each PC as that would mean notifying each employee that we are implementing the measure. One of our main goals is to track the files accessed by an certain employee.

Comment: "that would mean notifying each employee" - yes, that would it mean. But don't they have Windows computers already? How do they log on on their own machines? Does everyone use the same logon and same password on his machine? That's unbelievable...

Comment: If so, you can't track anything. Because someone just needs to walk over to a different machine, log on with the globally known credentials and access the file. It will be tracked as the computer of someone else.

Comment: If everyone has their own credentials, you can use the Windows authentication (SSO, Single Sign On) and they don't need a password at all (making access even simpler) and you'll be able to track individuals.

Comment: Thank you for the info. Working with servers is new to me so a lot of the policy options I haven't seen before. Each one has their own login on their Windows Machine. The drive on the Windows Server is mapped as a network drive. This specific drive is setup to authenticate using one username and password. This is a security issue which I will be addressing in the future, but for the time being I cannot notify employees of the tracking. Thank you for the assistance though, it seems SSO might be the best answer moving forward.